# Using NSUndoManager, how to register undos using Swift closures

Tags: swift, nsundomanager, lexical-closures

I am trying to grok how to use `NSLayoutManager` using Swift closures. I can successfully register an `undo` as follows:

```
doThing();
undoManager?.registerUndoWithTarget(self, handler: { _ in
    undoThing();
}
undoManager?.setActionName("do thing")
```

Of course I need to support `redo` which amounts to an undo of an undo. I can do that:

```
doThing();
undoManager?.registerUndoWithTarget(self, handler: { _ in
    undoThing();

    undoManager?.registerUndoWithTarget(self, handler: { _ in
        doThing();
    }
    undoManager?.setActionName("do thing")
}
undoManager?.setActionName("do thing")
```

But now I need to support an undo of the redo... hmmm.... ok:

```
doThing();
undoManager?.registerUndoWithTarget(self, handler: { _ in
    undoThing();

    undoManager?.registerUndoWithTarget(self, handler: { _ in
        doThing();

        undoManager?.registerUndoWithTarget(self, handler: { _ in
             undoThing();
        }
        undoManager?.setActionName("do thing")
    }
    undoManager?.setActionName("do thing")
}
undoManager?.setActionName("do thing")
```

As you can see its "turtles all the way down." How do I escape from this madness? i.e., in all the example code I can find, folks use the selector version of the code to register a method that can undo itself -- this is not obviously doable with the closure method I am using... How does one use the closure version and get unlimited undo/redo?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you're looking for is mutual recursion. You need two functions, each of which registers a call to the other. Here are a couple of different ways to structure it:

1. In `doThing()`, register the undo action to call `undoThing()`. In `undoThing`, register the undo action to call `doThing()`. That is:

   ```
   @IBAction func doThing() {
       undoManager?.registerUndoWithTarget(self, handler: { me in
           me.undoThing()
       })
       undoManager?.setActionName("Thing")

       // do the thing here
   }

   @IBAction func undoThing() {
       undoManager?.registerUndoWithTarget(self, handler: { me in
           me.doThing()
       })
       undoManager?.setActionName("Thing")

       // undo the thing here
   }
   ```

Note that you should **not** refer to `self` in the closure unless you capture it with `weak`, because capturing it strongly (the default) may create a retain cycle. Since you're passing `self` to the undo manager as `target`, it's already keeping a weak reference for you and passing it (strongly) to the undo block, so you might as well use that and not reference `self` at all in the undo block.

2. Wrap the calls to `doThing()` and `undoThing()` in separate functions that handle undo registration, and connect user actions to those new functions:

   ```
   private func doThing() {
       // do the thing here
   }

   private func undoThing() {
       // undo the thing here
   }

   @IBAction func undoablyDoThing() {
       undoManager?.registerUndoWithTarget(self, handler: { me in
           me.redoablyUndoThing()
       })
       undoManager?.setActionName("Thing")
       doThing()
   }

   @IBAction func redoablyUndoThing() {
       undoManager?.registerUndoWithTarget(self, handler: { me in
           me.undoablyDoThing()
       })
       undoManager?.setActionName("Thing")
       undoThing()
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Those are both great answers. Thanks for the tip on `self` -- I wonder how much memory I am leaking elsewhere...